# Use beans from a project in the xhtml of another project

Tags: jsf, maven, primefaces, ejb

I have several projects, within the same application, with a rough structure:

- parent

  - ear
  - ejb
  - persistence
  - web

I use Maven to solve all dependencies and too bundle everything nicely into a WAR, which I later deploy on JBoss.

My problem is that most of my model is in the ejb project and I need those beans either in the Backing Bean logic (in web) or directly called in the JSF .xhtmls (also in web).

I have scoured the internet, including stack overflow, and found tonnes of examples on SPRING and how to import/export modules. Well, since I'm not using it I do not know how to proceed any further.

So how do I import/use these beans from another project?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the technology stack you mentioned, might as well go for CDI as well. Regardless, if you're packaging everything as a WAR, that's just one module at runtime. Suppose you have the following structure:

```
--- WAR
 |--- any *.xhtml files can live here (public)
 |--- WEB-INF
   |--- web.xml (optional)
   |--- persistence.xml (optional) - declare persistence unit used from WEB-INF/classes
   |--- beans.xml (optional) enable CDI annotation scanning for WEB-INF/classes
   |--- faces-config.xml (optional) enable JSF annotation scanning in WEB-INF/classes
   |--- *.xhtml files can live here (private - usually templates, ui:composition, etc.)
   |--- classes
     |--- com.example - put managed beans here, EJBs, JPA etities or just about any other *.class
   |---lib
     |--- jpa.jar
       |--- META-INF
         |--- persistence.xml - persistence unit used in this jar
       |--- com.example - JPA entities can live here, gets mapped to WEB-INF/classes at runtime
     |--- ejb.jar
       |--- META-INF
         |--- ejb-jar.xml (optional) but can declare resources here
       |--- com.example - ejbs can live here, gets mapped to /WEB-INF/classes at runtime
     |--- faces.jar
       |--- META-INF
         |--- faces-config.xml - enables scanning JSF specific annotations in this jar
       |--- resources - this gets mapped to the WAR root at runtime, .xhtml can live here
       |--- com.example - put your @ManagedBean s here and @EJB inject anything from ejb.jar, gets mapped to /WEB-INF/classes at runtime
     |--- cdi.jar
       |--- META-INF
         |--- beans.xml - marks this as CDI bean archive
       |--- com.example - CDI beans can live here, gets mapped to WEB-INF/classes at runtime
```

Note that even though I have specifically separated jpa.jar, ejb.jar, faces.jar, and CDI.jar in the above structure, nothing says you have to - you can mix and match as you wish. The points to take away:

1. for any jar within a WAR's `WEB-INF/lib` classes get mapped to `/WEB-INF/classes` at runtime
2. `beans.xml` enables CDI
3. `faces-config.xml` enables JSF annotation scanning
4. `ejb-jar.xml` is not required anywhere, but you can take advantage of it
5. `web.xml` can live in `WEB-INF/`, but is not required
6. `web-fragment.xml` can live in the `META-INF` folder of any jar within `WEB-INF/lib` and gets merged into `web.xml`
7. `.xhtml` JSF files can live in the web app root (public) within `WEB-INF/` (private), and within `META-INF/resources` of any jar inside `WEB-INF/lib` - all these files get mapped to the web app root (i.e they can logically end up inside `WEB-INF/` if in the jar they are within `META-INF/resource/WEB-INF`)
8. `persistence.xml` can live in `WEB-INF` or inside `META-INF` of any jar inside `WEB-INF/lib`

That should just about cover it - let me know if anything is unclear or could be added.

Comment: Well somehow my Maven packages them strangely! Not all my beans end up in WEB-INF/classes. They are in a separate snapshot as I have configured them. What bugs me is that the implementation is only searching in WEB-INF/classes...

Comment: By beans, do you mean JSF managed beans or CDI beans or EJBs?

Comment: But it doesn't matter it's roughly the same it's just that NOT all of my classes get mapped to WEB-INF/classes. And that is in fact my problem. Thanks for the explanation, it helped with finding my packaging issues. I've fixed them with Maven now! I'll consider this the correct answer anyways, as you do offer insight on how to package beans to make them accessible!

Comment: By beans I meant EJB (@Stateless), most of them. Basically it wasn't  mapping all beans in my other jars to WEB-INF/classes.

P.S. I'll look into adding CDI as well!

Comment: Hmm, never had a problem, but yeah, CDI ftw :)